# bad substitution shell- trying to use variable as name of array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, variables

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( 2 4 5 8 15 )
a_2=( 2 4 8 10 )
a_4=( 2 4 8 10 )
a_5=( 10 12 )
a_8=( 8 12 )
a_15=( 2 4 )
numberOfTests=5
while [ $i -lt ${#array[@]} ]; do
    j=0
    currentArray =${array[$i]}
    *while [ $j -lt ${#a_$currentArray [@]} ]; do #### this line i get ->>>> bad substitution*
        ./test1.sh  "${array[$i]}" -c "${a_"$currentArray "[$j]}" &
        let j=j+1
    done
    let i=i+1
done
```

so Im trying this code, loop over an array(called array), The array should point out
the array number we are now looping(a_X). And every time to point out the current place and value.
can anybody help me how im using the $currentArray to work properly so I can know the length of the array and the value?
I get in the line I marked an error.
Thank you guys!

Comment: `bash` doesn't do nested parameter expansions. It's not clear how to accomplish what you want. What version of `bash` are you using? (Namerefs in `bash` 4.3 may make this easy/possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store the full names of the arrays, not just the numerical suffix, in `array`. Then you can use indirect parameter expansion while iterating directly over the values, not the indices, of the  arrays.

```
# Omitting numberOfTests has it does not seem to be used
array=(a_2 a_4 a_5 a_8 a_15)
a_2=( 2 4 8 10 )
a_4=( 2 4 8 10 )
a_5=( 10 12 )
a_8=( 8 12 )
a_15=( 2 4 )
for arr in "${array[@]}"; do
    currentArray=$arr[@]
    for value in "${!currentArray}"; do
        ./test1.h "${arr#a_}" -c "$value" &
    done
done
```