# Bash , use variable as name of associative array when calling value

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

This question [bad substitution shell- trying to use variable as name of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640763/bad-substitution-shell-trying-to-use-variable-as-name-of-array) does something similar to what I need but for arrays. I'm very new to bash scripting and what I need is to do something like this:

```
# input
humantocheck="human1"

declare -A human1
declare -A human2

human1=( ["records_file"]="xxxxx.txt")
human2=( ["records_file"]="yyyyy.txt")

echo ${$humantocheck[records_file]}
```

With expected output of:

```
xxxxx.txt
```

However I get a `bad substitution` error when I try this.

Comment: You would; `humantocheck` is not an array.  If anything is going to work, it'll be a variation on `${${!humantocheck}[records_file]}` but I'm not confident (I didn't find the magic combo).  (See [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler having a look at it. Still new to bash so it's all greek -)

Comment: Another section in the G[r]eek manual of relevance is [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). One possibility is to create a generic associative array `human` from either `human1` or `human2` and then reference that. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to assign whole associative arrays in one swell foop.  The best I've come up with uses a loop to copy the associative array element by element: `for key in "${!human1[@]}"; do human[$key]="${human1[$key]}"; done`. Generally speaking, using indirect variable names leads to complications, and a rethink/rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this with an indirect reference is:

```
ref=$humantocheck[records_file]
echo ${!ref}
```

[Bash: Indirect Expansion Exploration](http://ahmed.amayem.com/bash-indirect-expansion-exploration/) is an excellent reference for indirect access to variables in Bash.

Note that the `echo` command, which was intended to be a minimal modification to the original code, is unsafe in several ways.  A safe alternative is:

```
printf '%s\n' "${!ref}"
```

See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Comment: It works for me.  It's intriguing — I'm trying to fathom what it means about the implementation.  Well done!  I'd probably use `ref="$humantocheck[records_file]"` with double quotes to prevent mischief.  The key can also be in a variable, of course: `ref="$humantocheck[$key]"`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I have only a handful of keys in the array so I'm able to create variables like `human_file=$humantocheck[human_name]` at the top of my file and use `${!human_file}` as a sort of template variable for all other commands throughout the file! Really cool.

Comment: [Word splitting is not performed on expansions in assignments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting#Notes) so `ref=$humantocheck[$key]` is no less safe than `ref="$humantocheck[$key]"`.

Comment: @pjh question, using this syntax how would one check for the existence of a key? Atm `deps_file=$app_type[deps_file]` and `if [ -n ${!deps_file+1} ]; then echo Not set...; else echo key is set...;  fi` isn't working for me

Comment: @Jonathan, the code has missing quotes, and the echos are the wrong way round.  Try `if [ -n "${!deps_file+1}" ]; then echo 'Key is set' ; else echo 'Key is not set' ; fi`. It's better to use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]` in Bash code because, among other advantages, you mostly don't have to worry about quotes.

Answer (score 8):

This is exactly the scenario that the bash 4.3 feature namevars (borrowed from ksh93) is intended to address. Namevars allow *assignment*, as opposed to lookup alone, and are thus more flexible than the `${!foo}` syntax.

```
# input
humantocheck="human1"

declare -A human1=( ["records_file"]="xxxxx.txt" )
declare -A human2=( ["records_file"]="yyyyy.txt" )

declare -n human=$humantocheck # make human an alias for, in this case, human1
echo "${human[records_file]}"  # use that alias
unset -n human                 # discard that alias
```

See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for a comprehensive discussion of both associative arrays and indirect expansion in general.

Comment: from where I'm standing this should be the accepted answer.